# Error on deploying with Git on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm not able to deploy in Heroku. I'm getting `Permission Denied!` everytime. I have my repository already exists.

```
$ git remote -v
heroku  git@heroku.com:catapp11.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:catapp11.git (push)
```

But while I try to push in Heroku, I always get error.

```
$ git push -u heroku master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Did you add your ssh public key to your Heroku account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to upload to Heroku your keys. Follow [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys) or try:

```
heroku keys:add
```

Comment: Thank yu so much, it helped me. :)